# How do I track down my autostart issue?

Tags: windows-7, cd-drive

My auto start stopped working some time ago. I'm sure it was caused by some software conflict, but I'm at a loss to try and track down which one. Any suggestions are welcomed. I'm running Windows7 Professional 64-bit.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I found it. Needed to change a setting in about:config on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Open the *Control Panel*, then select *Default Programs*, and now you should see an option to manage your *AutoPlay* settings.  Select that and you will be presented with an incredibly long list of AutoStart hooks/events that will trigger various applications to start-up or take some specific action.

---

If you can't make sense of that long list, then tell me a little bit more about what functionality that you used to have that is not working anymore.  Specify the way that you want it to work- just for clarity and my understanding.

Personally, I turn AutoStart functionality off on purpose.  I'll elaborate why if you are curious.

Comment: "I turn AutoStart functionality off " You mean disable AutoPlay? No such thing as autostart, there is autorun and autoplay, autorun is by default disabled for security reasons in W7, and should be disabled in Vista and XP if it is not already.

Comment: I've already visited the AutoPlay settings. The box is checked for "Use autoplay for all media devices". Each device is set to "Ask me every time". However, the window never comes up after adding a device. It used to. It still does on my laptop with Windows7, but not with my desktop. Something is preventing that from happening.